# styling columns in table that uses CSV data through php

Tags: php, html, csv

I am looking to style my table columns for example make Author columns display for example "the book titles" in bold red while the prices in italic blue etc...

```
2012-03-11,paul,the book title,386,10,256
```

my php code

```
echo "<table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>   \n\n
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Date</th>
<th>Author</th>
<th>Title</th>
<th>Prices</th>
<th>Sales</th>
<th>Rank</th>
</tr>
</thead>";
$f = fopen("local/bookdata.csv", "r");
$i = 0;

while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) {
     echo "<tr class='$class".(($i%2)?'odd':'even')."'>";
        foreach ($line as $cell) {
                echo "<td style='font-weight: bold;'>" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>\n";
    $i++;
}

fclose($f);
echo "\n</table>";
```

Any help most welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

php

```
$classes = array('', '', 'title', 'price' , '', '');
// ...
foreach ($line as $idx=>$cell) {
    echo "<td class='{$classes[$idx]}'>". htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</td>";
}
```

css

```
td.title { font-weight: bold; color: red; }
td.price { font-style: italic; color: blue;  }
```

Comment: Don't forget about the good ol rows! tr:nth-child(even) {background: #CCC} tr:nth-child(odd) {background: #FFF}